# Setting/Registry key for each setting in Privacy tab 'cookies' slider?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-registry, cookies

I want to know which keys control the setting for the Privacy tab slider for cookies (in Internet Options).

I have the following official document, which outlines the following:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3
```

The the key "1A10" contains the value which control it. However I can only see a unique value for Block all Cookies, Medium and Accept all Cookies. When there is also High, Medium-High and Low. ANd strangley enough, the DWORD value for High, Medium-High, Medium and Low, are all the same, as specified in the article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569

Privacy Settings (1A10) is used by the Privacy tab slider. The DWORD values are as follows:

- Block All Cookies: 00000003
- High: 00000001
- Medium High: 00000001
- Medium: 00000001
- Low: 00000001
- Accept all Cookies: 00000000

Can anyone explain where the setting/key is, which identifies the difference between the 4 settings which all have the same DWORD value?

Thanks